# Can't get more than 50 messages through Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, message, inbox

Running

```
FB.api('/me/inbox', {limit:800}, function(response){ console.log(response)});
```

logs

```
data: Array[50]
summary: Object
```

to the console, clearly only 50 messages. Setting the limit to a less high value, say 51, produces the same result.

How can this be solved?

I have already looked at pagination (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023757/how-does-paging-in-facebook-javascript-api-works) , but as it seems, no pagination data is returned when I run this request.

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of this, which solved my problem: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8874143/facebook-graph-api-return-only-one-page-of-inbox
this question can be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the until parameter for pagination of your inbox.

`/me/threads?until=2011-05-01`

The new inbox is now called `threads` rather than inbox. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/thread/ (yes in the Graph API Explorer it is plural rather than what the documentation shows as singular)

Comment: I wonder when facebook will release this - threads is still in 'developer only' mode, and I have been waiting for over a year...