# FB.api pagination without nesting

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, pagination, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to generate a users entire friend list via Facebook's javascript API. I am able to get 50 (or so) of the users friends using the following call.

```
FB.api("me/friends",function(response){
//Do something with response
});
```

I know if the user has more friends I can get 50 (or so) more with the following code:

```
FB.api("me/friends",function(response){
    if (response.paging.next != "undefined"){
        FB.api(response.paging.next,function(response){
        }
     }
});
```

This however is not ideal because in order to get an indeterminately long friend list I just need to nest a whole bunch of FB.api functions and hope I have enough. Can anyone suggest another way?

Answer (score 12):

Try using recursion:

```
FB.api("me/friends", doSomething);

function doSomething(response){
   if (response.paging.next != "undefined"){
       FB.api(response.paging.next, doSomething);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you are right but you have to change the condition to `if (typeof response.paging === "undefined" || typeof response.paging.next === "undefined" ){console.log("data colllected");}else{ FB.api(response.paging.next, doSomething);}`