# How to get all comments of a facebook post using facebook SDK in Python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, recursion

I want to get all comments of a facebook post. We can extract comments by  passing the `limit()` in Api call But how we know the limit? I need all comments.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/10153608167431961?fields=comments.limit(100).summary(true)&access_token=LMN
```

By using this

```
data = graph.get_connections(id='10153608167431961', connection_name='comments')
```

I am getting few comments. 
How can I get all comments of a post?

**Edit**

```
import codecs
import json
import urllib

import requests
B = "https://graph.facebook.com/"
P ="10153608167431961"
f = "?fields=comments.limit(4).summary(true)&access_token="
T = "EAACb6lXwZDZD"
url = B+P+f+T


def fun(data):

    nextLink =  (data['comments']['paging']['next'])
    print(nextLink)
    for i in data['comments']['data']:
        print (i['message'])

    html = urllib.request.urlopen(nextLink).read()
    data = json.loads(html.decode('utf-8'))
    fun(data)

html = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
d = json.loads(html.decode('utf-8'))

fun(d)
```

It is giving the error

> KeyError: 'comments'

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement paging to get all/more comments: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/#paging

Usually, this is done with a "recursive function", but you have to keep in mind that you may hit API limits if there are a LOT of comments. It´s better to load more comments on demand only.

Example for JavaScript: [How does paging in facebook javascript API work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023757/how-does-paging-in-facebook-javascript-api-works)

Comment: Can you refer me to a working example of getting anything from facebook using pagination?

Comment: just take a look at the SO link in my answer, there is an example with javascript. you just need to do recursive calls to the "next" link, which is a simple api call.

Comment: I am working in python. I never work with javascript.  :)

Comment: recursive functions are a basic programming concept, there are probably thousands of examples available with google. for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479343/how-can-i-build-a-recursive-function-in-python

Comment: and when you know how to write a recursive function, the rest is straightforward, just look at the first link in my answer. in every api call, you get a "next" link, which is the api call for the next result batch.

Comment: I tried to implement the recursion but it is giving the error. Would you like to see the **Edit** in Question?

Comment: i don´t know much about pyhton, but you should debug "data". i guess the error means that data["comments"] cannot be found.